# Can‘t import my own module in Python 3.6.5/Pycharm

Tags: python, import, module

I am using python 3.6.5 and Pycharm.
I have two ".py" files named make_pizza.py and pizza.py. The picture below shows the path of the two files:
[image]

And details of two .py files are shown below:
1) pizza.py:

```
def make_pizza(size,*toppings):
"""Describe the pizza you want to make"""
print("\nMaking a " + str(size)
      + "-inch pizza with the following toppings:")
for topping in toppings:
    print("- " + topping)
```

2) making_pizza.py:

```
import pizza

pizza.make_pizza(16, 'pepperoni')
```

As shown above, I want to import module "pizza.py" in "making_pizzas.py" and use the "make_pizza" functions. However, when I run "making_pizza.py", it will not work and an error will show up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Softwares/Python3.6/Project0/making_pizzas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pizza
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pizza'
```

I am sure I put these two .py files in one folder named "Project0", and I marked the folder path as Sources Root. but the error is still there.

Comment: Try `from .import pizza`

Comment: @nawarkhede I tried your code but it shows: "ImportError: cannot import name 'pizza' "

Comment: Can u please show us output of `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Place `import sys; print(sys.path)` before `import pizza`

Comment: I use import sys; print(sys.path) and it shows:['C:\\Softwares\\Python3.6\\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Softwares\\Python3.6\\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64']

Comment: check if you selected the right directory (in the top right corner open folder icon)